# How to build delphi projects for WIN64 when units inside it uses DesignEditors DesignIntf?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, delphi-xe7

I am trying to migrate some code from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE7-WIN64. The scenario is DesignEditors is 32bit only since the IDE is 32 bit application. And the project I am migrating has units which have uses clause containing DesignEditors or DesignIntf or both.

Putting `-LUDesignIDE` in Build Configurations>Edit>Delphi Compiler>Compiling>Additional options to pass to compiler>-LUDesignIDE

Gives the following as first error on build

`[dcc64 Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'DesignIDE' not found`

I am using Delphi XE7 trial version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763075/component-package-where-to-divide-runtime-designtime-registration-etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you have a package which is both [design-time](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Design-time_Packages) and [run-time](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Packages) combined into one. In most scenarios however, you must [split your package into two different packages](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2011/06/runtimedesigntime-what-delphi-packages.html). One package is run-time (where you implement all of your actual library), and the other is design-time (which exposes your library to the IDE).

That being said, the design-time packages must work directly with the Delphi IDE. The Delphi IDE is 32bit, so the design-time package must also be 32bit. Whereas, your run-time package will support whatever platforms are needed. Your design-time package is only responsible for registering your components, property editors, etc. to the IDE.

Anything which has anything to do with the IDE (such as registering components, registering property editors, etc.) Must be in your design-time package which is only 32bit. Because of legal copyright issues, all design-time implementation must be in a design-time package, separate from your run-time package.

Start by creating a new design-time only package, same name but prefixed with `DCL`. Then, change your original package to run-time only. Create a new unit now in your new design-time only package. This unit will be dedicated to registering all IDE design-time interaction. Everything in your run-time package which relies on these design-time units must be converted over to this design-time package. These units which you cannot find are only compatible with the 32bit Delphi IDE.

The new design-time only package will then have to require your run-time package. You'll have to compile the run-time package first before you can compile the design-time package. Any time, you make changes to your library, you need to 1) re-compile the run-time package, 2) re-compile the design-time package, and 3) re-install the design-time package.

Comment: How do I proceed if my project does not make a package?

Comment: I'm telling you, you need to split your package into two. There's no other way. There's no simple option to do so. You need to research this subject and take action depending on how your package is implemented. Essentially, your `Register` procedure needs to be in a design-time only package.

Comment: I just searched the Unit which had designeditors in Uses. The file did't have have the word `register` in its content.

Comment: It all depends on your library. We cannot see your code, so we don't know how you're using your package. If you're not actually registering any components, property editors, or anything else in your package, then there's not even a need for a design-time package. Remove these units from your package and see where it crashes when you compile. That will tell you what is using them.

Comment: Saw the links. but they seem to work with building of packages.

Comment: I am using TClassProperty,TPropertyAttributes,TDefaultEditor... and they become undeclared when I remove Designeditors from USes

Comment: The third link is the most important. That's what shows you the difference, and why you need to split them up. Again, those usages must only be in your design-time package, not in your run-time package. There's legal copyright reasons behind this splitting up of package types.

Comment: @AEonAX: all of those classes you mentioned are **design-time** classes, and thus can only be used by **design-time** code.  They have no business being used in **run-time** code. Whatever you are using them for at run-time is **WRONG**. You **MUST MUST MUST** separate your design-time logic from your run-time logic. There is no other option. If you want help re-designing your code, you need to show the actual code.

Comment: I will need time to digest. But thanks for the help.

Comment: It is an absolute must in your scenario. If you want to support 64bit especially.

Comment: "How do I proceed if my project does not make a package?" - Now that I re-read your question, you make no mention of a package, when in fact that must be what you're using. The unit(s) you're using are design-only which points to the fact that your project(s) must be also a package which supports design-time interaction.

Comment: In other words, your units which use these design-time units need to be in a design-time package. Your existing unit(s) which use any design-time units must be migrated over to a design-only package. Packages come in the twos nowadays... Run-time and Design-time.

Answer (score 3):

The ToolsAPI units can be included in Win32 designtime packages, and nowhere else. You are trying to include them in a Win64 executable project. That is not allowed.

The solution is that you remove all the ToolsAPI units from your project.